# Create an applet to change LifeCycle of the card or other applets

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

Is it possible to write an applet that it has ability and privelege to change life cycle of the card or life cycle of the other applets? If so, how? Which classes and methods I must use?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you can. First of all you need to use some of Global Platfrom's classes in your program, and secondly you need the required privilege for changing life cycle of other applets or card from the ISD (You require it in your applet installation procedure)

Comment: That's totally right. Read the Global Platform Specification! Supposing you are refering to Javacard this is handled in Annex A

Comment: Thank,I know that change the lie cycle but I want know how to check that this operation do by JCRE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to write an applet which can change the life cycle of CARD as well as other applications, for this this some appropriate methods should be used. But this applet need some privileges. Any ordinary application can't do this, only privilege application can do this.

- Global Platform provide an interface `GPRegistryEntry`, you need to implement following method of this interface to change the life cycle of another application :

> `public boolean setState(byte bState)`

:
This method allows the Life Cycle state of this GPRegistryEntry to be transitioned to the requested target state.

- Global Platform also provide a class `GPSystem` wich provide following methods :

> `public static boolean setCardContentState(byte bState)`

:This method sets the Application specific Life Cycle State of the current applet context.

> `public static boolean lockCard()`

: This method locks the card.

> `public static boolean terminateCard()`

: This method terminates the card.

Hope this will help you.